# Confusion matrix across multiple raters

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
test_data <- data.frame(event= c("event1","event2","event3","event4","event5","event6","event7"),
                    rater1_1 = c("red", "orange", "red", "purple", "orange", "red", "yellow"),
                    rater2_1 = c("red", "orange", "orange", "purple", "orange", "red", "purple"),
                    rater3_1 = c("red", "red", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "red", "yellow"),
                    rater4_1 = c("orange", "orange", "blue", "orange", "orange", "red", "purple"), 
                    rater5_1 = c("blue", "blue", "purple", "orange", "orange", "blue", "yellow")
                    )
```

with the above data, i'm trying to create a confusion matrix where i can observe disagreement across all the raters for each event. that is, for event1, 3 raters gave "red" and 1 "orange" and 1 "blue."

i believe the best way to approach this would be to take each rater pair comparison (rater1 on y-axis and rater2 on x-axis) and then iterate and tally across all rater pairs.

i'm hoping for something that looks like below:

```
        red  orange  blue  yellow  purple
red      22    6      2      3      2
orange   6     13     1      4      1
blue     2     1      10     3      1
yellow   3     4      3      9      2
purple   2     1      1      2      9
```

(note: these values are made up, i didn't manually count the above)

i'm not even sure where to start. most confusion matrices i searched are comparing actual model output to predicted model output (e.g., [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409010/order-confusion-matrix-in-r)). any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure the logic used here. Maybe use the example data to show the desired output.

Comment: the desired output would be similar to table i put above. generally the agreement high for each rater pair (the diagonal) but some disagreement (the off-diagonal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this solution I am using the `dplyr` and `purrr` packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
# convert to long format
df_long <- test_data %>% pivot_longer(-event)

# df_long
# # A tibble: 35 x 3
#   event  name     value 
#   <fct>  <chr>    <fct> 
# 1 event1 rater1_1 red   
# 2 event1 rater2_1 red   
# 3 event1 rater3_1 red   
# 4 event1 rater4_1 orange
# 5 event1 rater5_1 blue  
# 6 event2 rater1_1 orange
# 7 event2 rater2_1 orange
# 8 event2 rater3_1 red   
# 9 event2 rater4_1 orange
#10 event2 rater5_1 blue  
# # ... with 25 more rows

# create function to compute the confusion matrix for two given events
create_confusion_matrix <- function(raters){
 df_long %>% filter(name %in% raters) %>% 
             pivot_wider(names_from=name,values_from=value) %>% 
             select(-event) %>% 
             table()
}

# lets try this function with rater1_1 and rater2_1
create_confusion_matrix(c('rater1_1','rater2_1'))
#        rater2_1
#rater1_1 orange purple red yellow blue
#  orange      2      0   0      0    0
#  purple      0      1   0      0    0
#  red         1      0   2      0    0
#  yellow      0      1   0      0    0
#  blue        0      0   0      0    0


# now we need to get all combinations of two raters
raters2 <- combn(unique(df_long$name),2,simplify=FALSE)


# raters2 is a list, each element is a vector containing 2 raters

# loop over the list and apply create_confusion_matrix for each element
result_list <- map(raters2,create_confusion_matrix)
# result_list is a list, each element is a confusion matrix

#we can them sum all theses tables

contingency <- Reduce('+',result_list)
#        rater2_1
#rater1_1 orange purple red yellow blue
#  orange     14      1   2      1    5
#  purple      6      4   0      3    0
#  red         5      1   9      1    9
#  yellow      0      4   0      3    1
#  blue        0      1   0      0    0

# getting rid of rater1_1 and rater2_1 in dimnames
dimnames(contingency) <- list(dimnames(contingency)[[1]],dimnames(contingency)[[2]])
#       orange purple red yellow blue
#orange     14      1   2      1    5
#purple      6      4   0      3    0
#red         5      1   9      1    9
#yellow      0      4   0      3    1
#blue        0      1   0      0    0

# sum symmetric cells and make contingency table lower triangular
# first lets extract the diagonal
# diag is needed twice, first to extract the diagonal from contingency as a vector
# second to convert this vector to a diagonal matrix
diag_contingency <- diag(diag(contingency))
# sum lower and upper matrices by adding the transposed matrix
# and substracting the diagonal (otherwise added twice)
contingency <- contingency + t(contingency) - diag_contingency
# we know have a symmetrical matrix
#        orange purple red yellow blue
#orange     14      7   7      1    5
#purple      7      4   1      7    1
#red         7      1   9      1    9
#yellow      1      7   1      3    1
#blue        5      1   9      1    0

# set the upper triangular matrix to 0
contingency[upper.tri(contingency)] <- 0

# we get this matrix in the end
contingency
#           orange purple red yellow blue
#orange     14      0   0      0    0
#purple      7      4   0      0    0
#red         7      1   9      0    0
#yellow      1      7   1      3    0
#blue        5      1   9      1    0
```

Comment: awesome. this is very close... instead of comparing of events, i need to compare raters. so for example, in the testing of `create_confusion_matrix()` that needs to be `create_confusion_matrix(rater1_1, rater2_1)` and the results look right. i'm not interested in comparing between events as much as i am between raters. 

i'm able to switch things around, but get stuck at the `combn()` line. here, i need to create combinations of raters, not events.

Comment: I tried `combn(unique(test_data[grep("_1", colnames(test_data), value = TRUE)]), 2, simplify = FALSE)` but this didn't work with the following `map()` and `Reduce()` commands.

Comment: got it!

`df_long <- test_data %>% pivot_longer(-event)` ...
`create_confusion_matrix <- function(raters){
  df_long %>% filter(name %in% raters) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from=name,values_from=value) %>% 
    select(-event) %>% 
    table()
}` ...

`create_confusion_matrix(c('coder1_1','coder2_1'))` ....

`events2 <- combn(unique(df_long$name),2,simplify=FALSE)` ...

`result_list <- map(events2,create_confusion_matrix)` ...

`Reduce('+',result_list)`

Comment: @b222 glad you found the solution, I have updated my answer

Comment: two questions. what is happening in the `pivot_wider(names_from=name,values_from=value) %>% ` section of the code. i get that pivot_wider is reshaping the df back to wide, but what does `names_from=name` and `values_from=value` accomplish?

Comment: also since the axes on the table are arbitrary (raters randomly assigned to either), is it possible to fold all the results from the top right quadrant down to the bottom left quandrant? e.g., there were 7 confusions of purple when others agreed it was orange, but it is split on both sides of the diagonal at 6 and 1.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the `pivot_wider` does the following: take all unique elements from the `names_from = name` = different raters and create one column for each rater (we only call the function with two elements in raters so two columns will be created), the  `values_from=value` argument tells us what to put inside those columns, here we will have the actual ratings from the raters. I will update my answer for the other questions

Comment: @b222, updated the answer, I hope I answered to all of your questions

Comment: many thanks. i appreciate both the help and detailed explanations.